# Parsing dynamic key and value nested json

Tags: parsing, jackson, gson, objectmapper

```
{
  "buildingNumber": 123,
  "apatmentNumber": "4567",
  "apartments": "123",
  "isActive": true,
  "possibleActions": [
    "ENTER",
    "EXIT"
  ],
  "enterVia": {
    "J1-B1": [
      "DEFAULT_ROUTE"
    ],
    "A1-D1": [
      "DEFAULT_ROUTE"
    ]
    },
  "SectionMap": {},
  "route": "abc|def (via xyz)"
  }
```

I have above sample JSON. Whole content inside "enterVia" is dynamic.
I have to read this nested Json (shown below) from a response and send it in another request.

```
  {
    "J1-B1": [
      "DEFAULT_ROUTE"
    ],
    "A1-D1": [
      "DEFAULT_ROUTE"
    ]
}
```

Please suggest a way if it is possible using Gson, ObjectMapper.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using ObjectMapper. Below is the code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class JsonParseTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String json = "{\r\n\t\"J1-B1\": [\r\n\t\t\"DEFAULT_ROUTE\"\r\n\t],\r\n\t\"A1-D1\": [\r\n\t\t\"DEFAULT_ROUTE\"\r\n\t]\r\n}";

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Map<String, List<String>> routesMap = null;
        try {
            routesMap = objectMapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<Map<String, List<String>>>(){});
        } catch (JsonParseException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("read response output: " +routesMap);


        objectMapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES, true);
        String jsonRequest = null;

        try {
            jsonRequest = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(routesMap);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("next request output: " +jsonRequest);
    }

}
```

Output of the program:

read response output: {J1-B1=[DEFAULT_ROUTE], A1-D1=[DEFAULT_ROUTE]}

next request output: {"J1-B1":["DEFAULT_ROUTE"],"A1-D1":["DEFAULT_ROUTE"]}